# How can I check if all processes pertaining to a sidekiq queue have been executed?

Tags: sidekiq

I have five queues and I need to check in one of them, if all processes are done. If yes, I need do something like to send a log.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! \o/

`Sidekiq::Queue.new("queue").size`

Comment: That indicates that the jobs have been fetched and are being worked on.  It does not guarantee the jobs are finished and successful.  To do that, you need Batches. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches

Comment: Thanks! I'll see that.